# Apple Safari disrupting image url's

Tags: magento, safari, mobile-safari

Has anyone every encountered this problem:

Apple's Safari v5 is disrupting the image urls on one of my magento v1.6.1 sites within the same domain. The site in question is http://store.guns-aws.com

When analyzing the lack of images, I have noticed that image urls are being disrupted from www.guns-aws.com to www.guns -aws.com [notice the space]

Ironically Safari 4 does not have this issue and the same site works perfectly fine with IE, FF, Opera and Chrome.

Thinking its a javascript error, I have also disabled java and still the problem persist.

All your help is appreciated.

p.s. Mangento wise, I have cleared the cache, reindexed the whole site to no avail.

With best regards

Fabian

Comment: The Image URL in Safari 5 shows like this http://www.guns%0a-aws.com/media/slider/01.jpg instead of http://www.guns-aws.com/media/slider/01.jpg. The %0a is extra...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the error within the database -> core_config_data [base_media_url] of the site in mention. [If you ask me how the error developed, I really don't know...]

One will not notice that the url is disrupted via magento's settings panel as the url would display as it should so.

Hence for anyone with this trouble, just go to the database via phpmyadmin, select the core_config_data table and check for the base_media_url of the effected site and amend accordingly.

With best regards

Fabian

Answer (score 1):

Try going to System > Config > Web > Unsecure and check the Base URL and Base Media URL and make sure there are no spaces.

To determine if its a javascript or server error, right click on the page and hit View Source. If the URLs there have the space, its the server's fault. If they don't have the space, and you only see it in the Inspector its Javascript. However, I suspect its the server not Javascript.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking in the same lines as I check the db and re installed everything from scratch... still the problem persists. These are the urls on page source: http://www.guns
-aws.com/media/slider/01.jpg when it should be http://www.guns-aws.com/media/slider/01.jpg As to base URL BASE Media and BASE Java these are all correct, no spaces their. In fact with firefox, IE9, Opera and Chrome, the images show up. Its is just this with Safari 5 that I have this issue as with Safari 4 it works perfect.