# WordPress Safari Broswer urls include line feed special character

Tags: wordpress, url, safari

I have been doing some testing. NOTE: This is only happening with the Safari browser.

I turned off all plugins and activated theme Twenty Ten (instead of my Catch Box child theme). Under this configuration all the menu items work fine EXCEPT the Home tab in the top menu which in Safari displays as follows:

```
http://standrewsspringlake.org%0A/
```

When I activate theme Twenty Eleven then ALL the main menu items AND the Home tab have the added characters.

When I activate theme Twenty Twelve then ONLY the Home tab has the problem.

The difference between these three themes is that Twenty Eleven shows the drop down menu items where the others do not.

All plugins and core WP are up to date but as I said, the above happened with all plugins turned off.

I can not find this error on any of my other WP sites.  I always put my WP install inside a folder and not in the root but this is how I do all my WP sites and I see no differences in the .htaccess files.

Could this be hosting related?  The only real difference is that this site is hosted on a HostGator Baby account and my others are on HostGator Hatchling or Business accounts or other hosts.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check this answer to similar problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8122229/850010 - Maybe your URL in the database is stored with this character

Comment: That was it!  I found that under options for the option_name "home" there was a return after the .org of the url.  I removed this and now everything works.  I wish I had posted here 3 weeks ago when I first became aware of the problem!  Thank you so much.

Comment: I added my comment as an answer in case you would like to accept the answer.

Comment: Good , Just like I said in my answer , you had to double check the "home" and "blog" urls under settings .. the best way to "check" is delete them and write again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your URL in the database is stored with this character.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8122229/850010) to similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

This character is a `linefeed` encoded character. `Line Feed = U+000A`

If you want to get rid of it , you should either :

- `check your inserted values` ( both in the `menu item` under `appearances -> menus`, AND in the `blog` and `home` urls under `general settings` and make sure there are no stray (empty) characters , or
- if in code (in your own theme ), you should use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) and / or [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) functions, depending on the rest of your code ( which you did not included in your question original question ).

As for the Twenty Twelve theme , it is almost sure one of the above , unless you also changed something in the `.htaccess` level .

For an additional verifying measure , I would also recommend disabling all plugins again before applying the above mentioned steps with twenty twelve (as some of them , especially the SEO related) might have such an effect if badly used / coded .

As a side note , and as a rule of thumb, it is always better to include some code in the question, for 2 reasons :

1. it will help the people reading the question to post specific code
   as an answer.
2. it will help YOU to try and understand the problem ( if not exactly
   `WHAT` then at least `WHERE` )

One question I do have : Is your content ( Menu items ) in ENGLISH or some other language , and do ALL the characters are always `%0A` linefeed?

Comment: Thank you for your considered reply.

Before posting here I had checked the general setting values, they seemed fine because the return was "hidden" below the one-line field.  I also checked the database but not for a return as I was unaware a "line feed" and "return" were the same thing.

I do appreciate your suggestion about posting code with my questions as a way to help people help me but here the error only appeared in the url window in the browser and not as part of the page code.

Thank you again for your help.  I will do my best to question better in the future.

Comment: About the code , I was refering to the theme code . It will still be a good practice to use both `trim()` and `urlencode()` .. Anyhow you might want to accept an answer for this question as to mark this as resolved ..